# python check unique id in file and count

Tags: python

In the following `file.txt` for each ID shown I need to check how many number of times the currency is found for an ID. How can i do this?

file.txt

```
  ID101\tbill is $200
  ID101\tyour bill
  ID101\t $200 again
  ID101\t$100 is the generated amount
  ID101\t$50 is your amount
  ID101\t$74 is the amount
  ID102\tNo bill
  ID102\tbill is $75
  ID103\t$65 is your bill
  ID103\tno bill
```

code

```
f=open("file.txt")
arr=[]
count = 0
for l in f:     
   col = 0
   for i in l.split("\t"):
      if col == 0:
         if i not in arr: //tocheck whether it is a new id or not
            arr.append(i)
         if col == 1:
            if "$" in i:
              count += 1
      col += 1
```

How to check the count for each ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will love [`defaultdict`s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        id, content = line.split("\\t")
        if "$" in content:
            counts[id] += 1
```

Note that this will completely omit `id`s where not a single line contains a `$` sign.

Comment: hmnn i get an error ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: No the contents are exactly same as above

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker:Please see edit 1.Not sure what am i doing wrong

Comment: @Rajeev: All the lines in your file need to contain exactly one tab character for this to work. If there is a blank line at the end, for example, you'll get this error. Try adding `print (line)` right before the `split()` and see where exactly the fail occurs.

Comment: print repr(l) gives me 'ID101\\tyour bill\n' and print l gives me ID101\tyour bill

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('file.txt')
ids = {}
for line in file:
    if line.find('$') > -1:
        line_array = line.split("\t")
        id = line_array[0]
        if not ids.has_key(id):
            ids[id] = 0
        ids[id] += 1

for k in ids:
    print k + ': ' + str(ids[k])
```